# React Router and onEnter/onChange

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to use `onEnter` and `onChange` from React Router, but I don't quite understand how. When I run simple functions from there, it works, like this:

```
<Route path="/tag/:slug" component={Archives} onChange={() => { console.log('awd'); }} />
```

But when I try to use a method from `Archives` component, it doesn't.

```
<Route path="/tag/:slug" component={Archives} onChange={this.method()} />
```

How can I use those methods?

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your method with your scope.

There are 2 ways to bind.

First one, directly on your onChange

```
<Route path="/tag/:slug" component={Archives} onChange={this.method.bind(this)} />
```

or,

Second one

```
this.method = this.method.bind(this)
```

Comment: I tried binding, it doesn't work either. Please note that I want to use methods from component I am linking to, not from where I currently "am"

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. So you need to add a ref="archives" on your `<Route path="/tag/:slug" component={Archives} ref="archives" onChange={this.method.bind(this)} />` and when your this.method called you can call your component's method like this.refs['archives'].myMethod()